# Setting a value to variable

Tags: php, variables

I have a problem assigning value to a variable in php.

Example what I am trying to do:

Suppose I have 3 variables and I want to assign the value of 3rd variable to 4th variable but in 3rd variable I want to use first 2 variables.

```
  $depth = 1;
    $forumcat = _cat;
    $f1_cat = 'some html code';
    $new = '';
```

Now I want to assign     $f1_cat to     $new variable

I know it can be done like     $new = $f1_cat but I want to do it like

```
$new = $f$depth$forumcat;
```

I mean in place of using '1_cat' I want to use the variables.
I tried the following

```
$new = "\$f{$depth}{$forumcat}";
```

but this statement assigns a string     $f1_cat but I want to assign     $f1_cat variable value.

How to do it?

Comment: Use dot like: `$f . $depth . $forumcat;`

Comment: What language/framework is this? You should specify this in tags instead of just `variables`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$new = ${'f'.$depth.$forumcat}; // This will contain value of $f1_cat
```

Also you may want to change    `$forumcat = _cat;` to  `$forumcat = '_cat';`. please note the single quotes added to _cat